# Compound nouns and phrases: Is there a difference between using "woman" or "female"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, compounds

I saw a flyer yesterday which had a bold part as ***Society of Women Engineers***

I thought to myself why it's not ***Female Engineers*** and the follow up question about the difference between ***Female*** and ***Woman*** when making the compound names.

Is there really a difference in connotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting aside contemporary issues of identity politics ...

*Female*  is an animal/biological distinction. There are female fish, female cats, female sheep, female giraffes, female humans.

A *woman* is an adult person (human) who is biologically female.

If we bring contemporary identity politics into the picture, a *woman* is a person who declares themselves to be so.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, female is an adjective and woman is a noun. Same for male/man. This has somewhat changed in recent years with the female/male being used as a noun, and woman/man being used as adjectives.  However there are some who take insult at the use of the adjective as a noun.

So, at least in modern usage, either "women engineers" or "female engineers" is acceptable usage.